# Fancybox Positioning Inside Facebook Canvas iFrame

Tags: facebook, fancybox, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-iframe, facebook-canvas

OK so I have a iframe canvas app with its height set to "Settable" with the facebook javascrip sdk calls to *FB.Canvas.setSize();* and *FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();*.  These are working perfectly, as the iframe gets set to a certain pixel height based on its content.

The problem is that when I make a call to Fancybox, it positions itself based on this height.  I know that's exactly what its supposed to do as the fancybox jQuery returns the viewport by:

(line 673 of latest version of *jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js*):

```
_get_viewport = function() {
return [
    $(window).width() - (currentOpts.margin * 2),
    $(window).height() - (currentOpts.margin * 2),
    $(document).scrollTop() + currentOpts.margin
];
},
```

But the problem is the iframe will, for a lot of viewers, be longer than their browser window.  So the Fancybox centers itself in the iframe and ends up only partly visible to the majority of viewers.  (i.e. iframe height is 1058px and users browser is say only 650px).

Is there a way to have fancybox just calculate the physical browser height?  Or do I need to change some settings in my Facebook canvas app to make it work?

I like how the only scrollbar is the one on Facebook (the parent, if you will).

All suggestions GREATLY appreciated!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For fancybox 2 try:

find:

```
_start: function(index) {
```

and replace with:

```
_start: function(index) {
    if ((window.parent != window) && FB && FB.Canvas) {
        FB.Canvas.getPageInfo(
            function(info) {
                window.canvasInfo = info;
                F._start_orig(index);
            }
        );
    } else   {
        F._start_orig(index);
    }
},

_start_orig: function (index) {
```

Then in function **getViewport** replace *return rez;* with:

```
if (window.canvasInfo) {
    rez.h = window.canvasInfo.clientHeight;
    rez.x = window.canvasInfo.scrollLeft;
    rez.y = window.canvasInfo.scrollTop - window.canvasInfo.offsetTop;
}

return rez;
```

and finally in **_getPosition** function replace line:

```
} else if (!current.locked) {
```

with:

```
} else if (!current.locked || window.canvasInfo) {
```

Comment: Hi there - I think this is the answer I am looking for - my fancybox slides are in the wrong position in the facebook browser. I tried to implement this code but didn't quite understand where to start and stop, if I was replacing code or adding to it. Could you clarify?

Answer (score 5):

As facebook js api provides page info, then we could use it, so

find

```
    _start = function() {
```

replace with

```
    _start = function() {
        if ((window.parent != window) && FB && FB.Canvas) {
            FB.Canvas.getPageInfo(
                function(info) {
                    window.canvasInfo = info;
                    _start_orig();
                }
            );
        } else   {
            _start_orig();
        }
    },

    _start_orig = function() {
```

and also modify _get_viewport  function

```
    _get_viewport = function() {
        if (window.canvasInfo) {
            console.log(window.canvasInfo);
            return [
                $(window).width() - (currentOpts.margin * 2),
                window.canvasInfo.clientHeight - (currentOpts.margin * 2),
                $(document).scrollLeft() + currentOpts.margin,
                window.canvasInfo.scrollTop - window.canvasInfo.offsetTop + currentOpts.margin
            ];
        } else {
            return [
                $(window).width() - (currentOpts.margin * 2),
                $(window).height() - (currentOpts.margin * 2),
                $(document).scrollLeft() + currentOpts.margin,
                $(document).scrollTop() + currentOpts.margin
            ];
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, i used 'centerOnScroll' :true, and now it works fine...

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Thankfully fancybox is accessable through CSS. My solution was to overwrite fancybox's positioning in my CSS file:

```
#fancybox-wrap {
    top:    20px !important;
}
```

This code places the fancybox always 20px from top of the iframe. Use a different size if you like. The !important sets this positioning even though fancybox sets the position dynamically at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it by positioning the Fancybox relative to the position of another element, in my case an Uploadify queue complete div that displays a view link after the user uploads an image.

Have a style block with a set ID like so:

```
<style id="style-block">
body { background-color: #e7ebf2; overflow: hidden; }
</style>
```

Then the link to open the Fancybox calls a function with the image name, width, and height to set the content and sizes. The important part is the positioning. By getting the position of the queue complete div, generating a new class declaration (fancy-position), appending it to the style block BEFORE the fancybox loads (!important in class will override positioning from fancybox), then adding the new class using the wrapCSS parameter in the fancybox options, it positions the fancybox exactly where I want it.

```
function viewImage(image, width, height) {
    var complete_pos = $('#image_queue_complete').position();
    var css_code = '.fancy-position { top: ' + complete_pos.top.toString() + 'px !important; }';
    $('#style-block').append(css_code);
    var img_src = '<img src="images/' + image + '" width="' + width.toString() + '" height="' + height.toString() + '" />';

    $.fancybox({
        content: img_src,
        type: 'inline',
        autoCenter: false,
        wrapCSS: 'fancy-position'
    });
}
```