# Fancy Box center within Facebook iframe fanpage

Tags: facebook, fancybox, facebook-iframe

Hi I have a 1500px high fan page in facebook.
The fancy box popup centers in the middle of the 1500px iframe.

CSS positioning of  #fancybox-wrap class to an absolute position (top:
 50px !important;) does not work!  If you are at bottom of page
 and fire the fancy box popup it is not visible until you scroll back to top of the page.

I looked at the following STACKOVERFLOW fix but this did not work:: 
 [Fancybox Positioning Inside Facebook Canvas iFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7893946/fancybox-positioning-insid)...

I am using the latest version of fancybox.

Thanks in advance for any help
 (am pulling my hair out :()

cheers
 Jaimie